# how to display my ez-page links?

Tags: zen-cart

how to display my ez-page links ?

I create the ez page ,but can not see any links in index. why? how to display it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the header, sidebox and footer indicators are on, it should display in your header, sidebox and footer.

Perhaps you changed one of these files or didn't enable the sidebox?

Header: includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/common/tpl_header.php

Footer:  includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/common/tpl_footer.php

Sidebox: Turn on EZPages sidebox in admin->tools->layout boxes controller

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this not to long ago aswell.

You will have to enter a sort order other then 0 to make it show up anywhere.

I hope this helped.